# Google Cloud Network Load Balancer - Health checks always unhealthy

Tags: windows, networking, server, cloud, load-balancing

I tried to set up a network load balancer on google cloud but the heath check always returns unhealthy.

I give you the steps that i did follow

- I created two windows servers 2012 R2 instances
- I checked that the port 80 is open to public over both instances
- I created the forwarding rules and Google Cloud gave me a External IP
- I set up the external IP in a Network loopback interface on both server instances
- I created a Network Route that forwarding the traffic on both instances (route menu)
- I created another Network Route for the  169.254.169.254/32 (Source of Network load balancer traffic) and Pointing to both windows instances server
- I created the same site (example.com) on IIS 8 in both instances server and the site is running correctly.
- The DNS settings of the domain example.com is pointing to the external IP google cloud that I using for Network load balancer
- I configured the health check

  - PATH : /
  - Protocol : HTTP
  - HOST: example.com
  - Session Afinity : Client IP
- I created a Target Pool and I added both server instances and heath check
- I Asigned the target pool  to forwarding rule

When I select the Target Pool option, both instances marked as Unhealthy for the external IP that Google cloud gave me and I don't know why this happens.

I see the web page is switching the server instances randomly all the time.

Your Help is apreciated!, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to add any GCE Network Route.
- The GCE agent is taking care of adding the load balancer IP to the VM's network configuration. There is no need to do it manually. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-windows
- IIS must respond to requests on the LB IP:

  - Check the IIS bindings from IIS manager. Reset IIS.
  - Confirm from `netstat` that IIS is listening on 0.0.0.0 or the load balanced IP.
  - Access the LB IP from one of the servers. It should work.
- The GCE firewall must allow traffic from the clients' IPs and also from the metadata server (169.254.169.254). The metadata server is used for healthchecks.

Network Load Balancing tutorial. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/example

Comment: Thanks I have solved a lot time ago but thank you very much for your help